# Infinite run of for loop

Tags: java, arraylist, infinite

The FOR condition generates an endless printout. I really don't know how that can happen. There is only one entry as an instance in Books. What did I do wrongly?

```
package LOIoefeningen;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Handin 
{


        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {


            String title = null;
            String author = null;




            Possessor Bookworm   = new Possessor("Bookworm", new Books(title, author));

            ArrayList<Books> book = new ArrayList<>(); 


          for (int i = 0; i < book.size(); i++)
          {

          book.add(new Books("Pietje Puk", "Henri Arnoldus"));
          System.out.println(book.get(i));

          }      

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are adding book every time you are in loop. Thus book.size() keeps on increasing making it a moving target and resulting in infinite loop

Comment: @deadzg_devil see my comment below!! but thanks!! in the first place!!

Comment: Do you maybe also know how to get ride of the hexadecimal output?

Comment: Also, when fixing you will want the loop to be `i < book.size();`

Comment: Override `toString` in book to get rid of the hex output.

Comment: @SephB sorry I don't get that, can you explain closer?

Comment: @ScaryWombat got that already. But thanks!!

Comment: @twannemann I was not 100% sure what you where meaning, but assumed when you print `book.get(i)` you get an ugly hex string of it's class and address. If you override toString in the Books class you will get what ever you return. `    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return <return the string you want to display here>;
    }`

Comment: @SephB well still don't get it. Do you want me to add somewhere in the class Book' 'toString'? or do you want me to remove 'toString'?? anyway the code 'toString' as a plain text does not occur in the class Books. The term override is not clear to me.

Comment: @SephB is meaning https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140402/how-do-i-print-my-java-object-without-getting-sometype2f92e0f4

Comment: @SephB and Scary Wombat... it doesn't seem to work. It's pretty unclear to me how to resolve the problem.

Comment: @twannemann Dont radically change your question.  Now all comments and answers do not make sense for people looking at this in the future.

Comment: BTW `public Books(String t, String s) toString()` is totally meaningless.  As per the link I gave you the `toString` method should be something like `public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}`

Comment: @ScaryWombat, guess you are right. But I can post only one question in 90min. But  I didn't overlook the consequences indeed.

Comment: You could have edited tour question. which I suggest you do now before this question is downvoted more and deleted

Comment: @SephB and Scary Wombat... now I got it. It works!!! thank. And I will change my question as it was originally.

Comment: so maybe upvote and/or accept @SephB answer

Answer (score 0):

You are adding a new book each time through the loop. Move `book.add(new Books("Pietje Puk", "Henri Arnoldus"));` before the loop.

Comment: AAAHHHHH you made me feel so STUPID!! haha thanks. I think I am busy for too long time!!

Comment: so true! ! ! ! ! ! ! !